# Are the cascading ciphers in Veracrypt susceptible to the meet-in-the-middle attack? (MITM)

Tags: ciphers

**Veracrypt offers [cascades of ciphers.](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Cascades.html) 
Are these cascades (at least those comprised of two ciphers) susceptible to the meet-in-the-middle attack? Why not?**

For example:

> AES-Twofish
>
> Two ciphers in a cascade operating in XTS mode (see the
>   section Modes of Operation). Each 128-bit block is first encrypted
>   with Twofish (256-bit key) in XTS mode and then with AES (256-bit key)
>   in XTS mode. Each of the cascaded ciphers uses its own key. All
>   encryption keys are mutually independent (note that header keys are
>   independent too, even though they are derived from a single password –
>   see Header Key Derivation, Salt, and Iteration Count). See above for
>   information on the individual cascaded ciphers.

Meet-in-the-middle:

[image]

Comment: Not going to answer without more research, but my intuition is that it is _technically_ vulnerable, but would require 2^256 space, which theoretically isn't even possible.

Comment: Also meet in the middle is used to shorten the attack when multiple rounds of the same algorithm were used to increase the effective key size. I *think* that the cascades of ciphers is used to protect against a flaw being found in one of the algorithms. That is, it's not done to create a key with 384 bits. So a meet-in-the-middle is not even appropriate to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is vulnerable to a meet-in-the-middle attack.** In particular, the three 256-bit ciphers do not provide you with 768-bit security. Instead, it provides "only" 512-bits of security, and a proper meet-in-the-middle attack would require an obscene amount of storage space to pull off as well. This is not a problem though, because the cascading ciphers are not used to increase the keyspace. In fact, the largest hash that is used to derive the password has a 512-bit output. The real reason multiple ciphers are used is to alleviate concerns that one or more of the ciphers has a fatal *cryptographic* weakness that allows for breaking it faster than brute force. Whether or not this is a reasonable concern is debatable, as all the options are quite solid, but that was the intention.